# Comparing Characters (ARM Assembly)

Tags: assembly, char, compare, character

I'm trying to compare a Character from a Char-Array with a char in my assembly code.

This is the C-Code I use to start the assembly code:

```
char a[] = "abc";
char b = 'a'; 
int size = 3;

int d = _asm_main(a);
printf("Char a: %s\n",a);
printf("Erg:%d\n",d);
```

and this is the assembly code:

```
_asm_main:

push {r6,r7,r8,lr}

mov r8,r0

ldr r7,[r8,#2]
mov r6,r7
b compare

compare:

cmp r6,#'c'
beq true
b false

true:

mov r0,#1
b end

false:

mov r0,#2
b end

end: 

pop {r6,r7,r8,pc}

BX lr
```

It works for 'c' but if I try it with 'a' or 'b' I always get into the false lable. I don't get why it works for one of the three and not for the other two.

Comment: You are loading 4 bytes instead of 1. `c` just happens to be at the end of the string and presumably followed by 3 zero bytes by chance so your comparison works. You should use `ldrb`. PS: learn to use a debugger. Also, your `bx lr` is never reached since you `pop` into `pc`.

Answer (score 1):

A crude illustration using ldrb to deal with the ASCII byte and gdb debugger.

```
.data
        array:          .string "abc"
.text
        .global _start
_start:
        nop
        ldr r0,=array
        ldrb r1, [r0,#0]
        ldrb r2, [r0,#1]
        ldrb r3, [r0,#2]
...
```

gdb:

```
16              ldr r0,=array
(gdb) si
17              ldrb r1, [r0,#0]
(gdb)
18              ldrb r2, [r0,#1]
(gdb)
19              ldrb r3, [r0,#2]
(gdb)
_exit () at stuff.s:25
25              mov r7, #1
(gdb) i r
r0             0x20094  131220
r1             0x61     97
r2             0x62     98
r3             0x63     99
```